# Why example.com/foo/ works but example.com/foo doesn't?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a very small question. I created a .htaccess file that suppose to rewrite a condition `example.com/user/foo/bar` as `example.com/user.php?username=$1&tab=$2` so username name will be foo and the viewing tab must be bar.

But when there is no bar data provided exactly like `example.com/user/foo/` it goes to user with default tab (default tab is generated in script.php file).

But I saw some website that they can do it just like example.com/user/foo, without the / at of the line. When I do `example.com/foo` to go to user, it says page not found. My correspoding .htaccess line is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ user.php?username=$1&tab=$2 [L]
```

Please help me with this sitiation.

Comment: Basically your rule is requiring the URL have two non-leading `/` in it, but `/foo/bar` only contains ONE non-leading `/`, so won't get matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your match rule is `^user/(.*)/(.*)$`, which means that the second slash **must** be there (since it's specified), but the text afterwards is optional (since `*` matches zero or more characters).

Really, I'd add two rewrite rules to do both differently (and to prevent using complicated regex), e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ user.php?username=$1&tab=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*) user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can make the 2nd parameter optional:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?(?:(.*)|)$ user.php?username=$1&tab=$2 [L]
```

As long as you don't mind having no value for `$_GET['tab']`